# Shell command to delete \n on 1 out of 2 line on a file

Tags: shell

I'm looking for a shell command to delete the return chariot on one line out of two.
I have a file like this :

```
1.32640997
;;P
1.14517534
;;P
1.16120958
;;P
...
```

And I would like something like this:

```
1.32640997;;P
1.14517534;;P
1.16120958;;P
...
```

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using awk

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%2==0?ORS:"")}' File
1.32640997;;P
1.14517534;;P
1.16120958;;P
```

This prints each line followed by nothing for odd lines or followed by the output record separator for even lines.

#### Using sed

This works by reading in lines in pairs:

```
$ sed 'N; s/\n//' File
1.32640997;;P
1.14517534;;P
1.16120958;;P
```

`N` reads in the next line and `s/\n//` removes the newline.

Comment: For the record, this is better than my `paste` solution, because sed and awk are more widely available (for example no `paste` in Git Bash if I recall correctly)

Answer (score 3):

#### Using GNU `paste`

```
paste -d '' - - < file
```

#### Using BSD `paste`

```
paste -d '\0' - - < file
```

`paste` produces two columns from stdin with `- -` as parameters, 3 columns with `- - -` as parameters, and so on.

`-d` is to specify a column separator, use `'\0'` for no separator.

#### Using Perl

```
perl -ne 'chomp($prev = $_); print $prev, scalar <>' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xargs:

```
xargs -n 2 -d '\n' printf '%s%s\n' <file
```